# How to show that $f\in\mathcal L[0,1]$ (Lebesgue Integrable)

Tags: measure-theory, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> **Question:** Let $f$ be the function defined on $[0,1]$ by
> $$
> f(x)=
> \begin{cases} 
>       n(-1)^n & \textrm{if }\frac{1}{n+1}<x\leq \frac{1}{n} \\
>       0 & \textrm{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
> (a) Is $f$ a bounded function?
> (b) Is $f\in\mathcal L[0,1]$?
> (c) Does the improper Riemann integral $\int_0^1f(x)dx$ exist?

For (a), I had hard time to interpret the function like how it eat $x$ and spit out something not explicitly $x$ related. I try to understand it by, $$\frac{1}{11}<0.1\leq\frac{1}{10}\implies f(0.1)=10(-1)^{10}=10$$

Is there any other (efficient)way to interpret it? $\tag 1$
Hence, $x\rightarrow 0 \implies f(x)\rightarrow \pm\infty$ (unbounded)

For (b), I know several properties,

$(1)$ Let $f$ be an unbounded function defined on $[a,b]$. For $N>0$ define
$$
{}^Nf(x)=
\begin{cases} 
      f(x) & \textrm{if }f(x)\leq N \\
      N & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
we say $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[a,b]$ if ${}^Nf$ is Lebesgue integrable for all $N>0$ and $\lim_{N\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\int_a^b{}^Nf\right)$ is finite. In this case $\int_a^b f$ si defined to be $$\int_a^b f=\lim_{N\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\int_a^b{}^Nf\right)$$
$(2)$ Let $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$. Then $f$ is Lebesgue Integrable if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a measurable partition $P$ such that $$U[f,P]-L[f,P]<\epsilon$$
But couldn't decide where to start.

For (c) I have no clue.

Any help will be appreciated. TIA

Comment: TIA means “thanks in advance.” @AnneBauval How did you quickly recognize the harmonic series pattern. Could you explain it for me and thanks again for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) is ok.

b)(1) is not. For your (unbounded) $f$ to be Lebesgue integrable, it is necessary (by definition) that $∫|f|<∞,$ which is not the case:
$$\sum_{n\ge1}n\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{n+1}=+\infty.$$

c): the answer is yes:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(-1)^n\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}=-1+\ln2.$$

Answer (score 0):

I can help with (c), by expanding on Anne Bauval's comment.

It helps to draw the graph of this function.

This function is on [0,1]. Consider the partition $\{1,\frac{1}{2},...\frac{1}{n}..\}$ and define the function on these intervals. Taking the improper Riemann Integral is the same as computing the area enclosed by this function and the x-axis. So you will get,

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ((-1)^{n}n)(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})$

You can see that this is the alternating harmonic series, with a few adjustments. The alternating harmonic series is conditionally convergent.